# ng-select in Angular 8 application - Runtime Error related to NgSelectComponent

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to use ng-select in my Angular 8 application.
I'm getting a runtime error:

```
core.js:6249 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgSelectComponent -> NgSelectConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgSelectComponent -> NgSelectConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgSelectConfig!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgSelectComponent -> NgSelectConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgSelectComponent -> NgSelectConfig]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgSelectConfig!
```

Here's what I did:

1. Installed ng-select using npm install --save @ng-select/ng-select
2. included this in my app.module.ts

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
```

And I included NgSelectModule in the imports
3) In my component, I added:

```
<ng-select [items]="xyz"
         bindValue="XyzID"
         bindLabel="Description"
         [multiple]="false"
         placeholder="Select Xyz"
         searchable="true"
         clearable="true"
     formControlName="xyz">
 </ng-select>
```

3. In component.ts,  xyz exists as an array of objects (Description and XyzID are properties of the objects)
   I added:

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
```

4. In index.html I added a theme

```
 <link href="node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css rel="stylesheet">
```

I am using reactive forms.

5. After looking at the error message, I tried pulling in NgSelectConfig - although in the examples I saw online for ng-select, I didn't find any that were doing that.
   Then I got an error looking for a dependency - ConsoleService, which exists in @ng-select/ng-select/esm5/lib/console.service. I tried to explicitly import that, but still got errors.

Thank you for any help on this.

Comment: @NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NgSelectModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) did you do that in app module?

Comment: Not sure about this specific error, but your css in step 4 will fail in a production build.. this needs to be done inside angular.json..

Comment: @AbuSufian thanks, yes I did do that.

Comment: @MikeOne thanks, I'm just trying to get it working in development for now but will make a note to do that for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgSelectConfig } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { ɵs } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
```

and then in providers Array

```
providers: [NgSelectConfig, ɵs],
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I had to include ConsoleService, which ng-select exports as "es"

So, in my app.module.ts, I had to add:

import { NgSelectConfig } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { ɵs } from '@ng-select/ng-select';

And in providers, I added: NgSelectConfig and es

Hope it helps someone else with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed right version of `ng-select`.
Please check package.json
as per the docs https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#versions

### Versions

[image]

Just change your package.json from "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.0" to "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.0.0".
It should work!
reference https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/issues/1602#issuecomment-625420381

Answer (score 0):

Add `NgSelectModule` in `AppModule`

```
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
```

As follows

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    NgSelectModule, // This line
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```